# how to correct error in the dart mixin override member

Tags: dart, overriding

the following is my dart code :

```
mixin MessageBody {
  Schema get schema;
  List<int> get intList;
}

class Message with ZigZag, MessageBody, Radians {
  @override
  final Schema schema; //error: isn't a valid override ,why?
  @override
  final List<int> intList; //same , correctly, why?

....
}
```

Why did the above error occur?
and how to correct it?

Comment: You need to initialize `schema` and `intList`, probably with a constructor like `Message(this.schema, this.intList);`. See https://dart.dev/language/constructors#initializing-formal-parameters